# How do I break blocks with command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am familiar with the `/setblock` command, but I'm having trouble whenever I try to replace a block with air. The chat reads in red text, "Cannot place blocks outside of world", though I'm putting in the right coordinates. I can't seem to figure it out, can you help me? Command:

```
/setblock ~-147 ~74 ~-150 minecraft:air destroy
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at your command:

```
/setblock ~-147 ~74 ~-150 minecraft:air destroy
```

Notice that you have a `~` before every coordinate, meaning that you will replace a block relative to your position, and being 74 blocks above you, it might be outside the world.
If you want to destroy a block at `(-147,74,-150)` you should remove the `~` like so:

```
/setblock -147 74 -150 minecraft:air 0 destroy
```

As user3878893 pointed out, you also need to include a data value for the block to be placed. For regular blocks just use a `0` (as above).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 /setblock -147 74 -150 minecraft:air 0 destroy
```

Or

```
/fill -174 74 -150 -174 74 -150 air
```

Comment: Care to explain in a little detail maybe?

Comment: scusme, I don't speak a good english, so I can't explain more...

Comment: Try "minecraft:air 0 destroy" or simply remove "destroy"

Comment: Thank you for the help, I figured out that I had to put the command in like this to work /setblock -147 74 -150 minecraft:air 1 destroy  Thank you guys again I was getting pretty frustrated

Comment: Or you can use /setblock -147  74 150 air 0 replace

Comment: You are the welcome: feel free to ask again what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it says "Cannot place blocks outside of the world" is because the place where it wants to remove the block with air is outside the loaded area.

If you're on java then what is considered not "outside of the world" is anything inside an 8 chunk perimeter

If you're on bedrock then you can set the perimeter as a slider when editing the world the slider says simulation distance and you can set it higher the stronger your device is, it starts at 4 then 6 then 8 chunks is the max (though i might be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys i found and easy way of placing and destroying a block. The command is

`/setblock <x> <y> <z> (type of block) 0 destroy`

It doesn't matter if you put the / in the front of the command it works either way.